# What's the name of the short story in which a man walks home from the future?

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Man gets sent to the future. Walks back. His arrival at departure time causes huge blast that changes the world into what we see in snapshots of the surroundings at each step he takes trying to return to what won't/will not have been there. Story name and author, please?

Answer (score 10):

It's just called *The Man Who Walked Home*, by James Tiptree, Jr. You can [read it online here](http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/9781625791542/9781625791542___2.htm).

Comment: Comically that link is the first result on Google (excepting this page) when typing in the question above.

Comment: ALL HAIL GOOGLE!! _James Tiptree, Jr_ was a pseudonym for Dr. Alice Sheldon.